# In javafx while i am trying to execute this code my screen is not loading without showing any errors

Tags: javafx-2

`FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(../staff_page/Staff_page.fxml));`/*In javafx while i am trying to execute this code my screen is not loading without showing any errors*/

Comment: No more code? No stack trace? This is not magic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably add quotes before and after the path?!

Nobody can give you an answer to that question if you do not give any proper context.
Please add more information in order to solve the problem.